# Probability and expectation value of an RV show me my mistake

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 5 balls of different color in a bowl, we pick one and put it back, we repeat this procedure 20 times.

a) what is the probability that every ball will be picked at least once

b) What is the expectation value of number of colors picked (in this 20 repetitions)

a) Let

$A$- be an event of picking balls of all colors in this 20 times, i.e. every ball at least once.

and

$\Omega$- The Sample Space for 20 picks

Then $\bar{\bar{A}}=5^{16}\times4\times3\times2\times1$
and $\bar{\bar{\Omega}}=5^{20}$
so $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{24}{625}$$
**I CANNOT BELIEVE THIS!!!! IT'S SO LITTLE....**
So What's wrong?

b) Let $X$ be rv denoting number of colors, we have:
$$\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}X(\omega)\mathbb{P}(\omega)=\frac{1^{20}\times5}{5^{20}}+2\times\frac{2^{20} \times {{5}\choose{2}}}{5^{20}}+3\times\frac{3^{20}\times{{5}\choose{3}}}{5^{20}}+4\times\frac{4^{20}\times5}{5^{20}}+5\times\frac{5^{16}\times4\times3\times2}{5^{20}}=\frac{5+10\times(2^{21}+3^{21})+5\times 4^{21}+5^{17}\times4\times3\times2}{5^{20}}\approx 0.42$$

And once again **THIS CANNOT BE!!!**

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've grossly undercounted the size of $A$.  The reason is because $5^{16}$ counts the number of outcomes for the first $16$ draws, but ignores whether you've already drawn all five colors.  Then when you multiply by $4!$, you are assuming that those first $16$ draws did not result in getting all five colors.  So $A$ is not so small.

A better way to count is to look at the complementary event, in which at most $4$ colors are obtained.  Ignore one of the five balls.  There are $4^{20}$ outcomes in which the remaining $4$ balls can be chosen.  So if you repeat this logic, you would think that the complement would be $5(4^{20})$; but now you've overcounted those cases where you've obtained only $3$ or fewer colors.  So you look at those outcomes:  you have $\binom{5}{3} \cdot 3^{20}$ ways to get $3$ or fewer colors; $\binom{5}{2} \cdot 2^{20}$ ways to get $2$ or fewer colors; and $\binom{5}{1} \cdot 1^{20}$ ways to get $1$ color.  So by the principle of inclusion-exclusion, the number of outcomes in the complement of $A$ is $$\sum_{k=1}^4 (-1)^k \binom{5}{k} k^{20} = 5462700780625,$$ and the total size of $A$ is $$5^{20} - 5462700780625 = 89904730860000.$$  The desired probability is $$\frac{143847569376}{152587890625} = 0.9427194306625536.$$

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that

$$
5^{20}-\sum_{k=1}^4(-1)^k\binom5kk^{20}=\sum_{k=0}^5(-1)^{5-k}\binom5kk^{20}=5!\cdot\left\{20\atop5\right\}\;,
$$

where $\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) that counts the ways of partitioning $20$ draws into $5$ non-empty sets. (The factor $5!$ accounts for the ways to assign the $5$ colours to these sets.)

Answer (score 2):

I got 0.942353924769 $=1-5\times 0.8^{20}$, where the second term is the probability that one ball will never be chosen,i.e. for each ball,all other balls may be chosen, and there are 5 possible cases of this nature.  There is some inaccuracy as I have not considered the possibilities that more than one ball may be missed from all the selections.

---

After adjusting for the possibility that two balls may completely missed (counted twice) I get 0.942719540613006

Comment: Among a million simulated 20-draw experiments, I got all five colors in about 94.3% of them and only four unique colors in about 5.7% (other outcomes negligible). R code `> nr.dif.col = replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(1:5, 20, rep=T)))); mean(nr.dif.col==5)` returned  0.942723 on first run,  0.942850 on 2nd run.